# Pandas series add index and value at the beginning of the series object

Tags: python, pandas, series

I got a pandas Series object with an index starting from `'2020-01-01 01:00:00+00:00'` till `2020-12-19`. I would like to add the index `'2020-01-01 00:00:00+00:00'` with the value `np.nan`.

```
data_dict[i]
date_time
2020-01-01 01:00:00+00:00    13
2020-01-01 02:00:00+00:00    13
2020-01-01 03:00:00+00:00    13
2020-01-01 04:00:00+00:00    13
2020-01-01 05:00:00+00:00    13
                              ...
2020-12-18 20:00:00+00:00    25
2020-12-18 21:00:00+00:00    25
2020-12-18 22:00:00+00:00    25
2020-12-18 23:00:00+00:00    25
2020-12-19 00:00:00+00:00    20
```

When I use:

```
nan = pd.Series([np.nan], index=['2020-01-01 00:00:00+00:00'])
data_dict[i].append(nan)
data_dict[i].sort_index()
```

seems like nothing happens?

```
data_dict[i]
date_time
2020-01-01 01:00:00+00:00    13
2020-01-01 02:00:00+00:00    13
2020-01-01 03:00:00+00:00    13
2020-01-01 04:00:00+00:00    13
2020-01-01 05:00:00+00:00    13
                              ...
2020-12-18 21:00:00+00:00    25
2020-12-18 22:00:00+00:00    25
2020-12-18 23:00:00+00:00    25
2020-12-19 00:00:00+00:00    20
```

How would I add it at the right place(ie: at the beginning of the series object)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If use `.append` new data are added to end of `Series`, for correct order sorting values of `DatetimeIndex`:

```
s = s1.append(s2).sort_index()
```

If need to append to start of `Series`, swap order - add second `Series` to first one:

```
s = s2.append(s1)
```

EDIT: Here is necessary assign back `Series.append` and create `DatetimeIndex` in added Series:

```
nan = pd.Series([np.nan], index=pd.to_datetime(['2020-01-01 00:00:00+00:00']))
data_dict[i] = data_dict[i].append(nan)
data_dict[i] = data_dict[i].sort_index()
```

Comment: @oakca - It looks like you forget assign back, added to answer.

Comment: sadly sort_index() does not work because: `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'Timestamp'`

Comment: @oakca - `nan` has no DatetimeIndex, you need create it. EDITed.